# Weighty doesn't work in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

[image]

Above is what I want to achieve:

1. on the east of the `JFrame` is a fixed 400 width `JPanel`.
2. the panel uses `GridBagLayout`.
3. components in this panel all stretches horizontally
4. the last component fills the extra y space
5. the last component is a `JscrollPane` wrapping a `JTable`.

I have had many trials, all failed:

1. I tried to setPreferredSize of the panel, then the inner components won't stretch horizontally. (I know how use a GridBagConstraints, or I think I know)
2. I tried to setSize of the panel, then size is actually determined by the JscrollPane.
3. I tried to warp the JscrollPane in another JPanel (because I do not trust JScrollPane that much), no use.
4. The GridBagContraints.weighty never functions in this project, however functions well elsewhere.

So I think the problem is with the JTable, it always make a prox. 300*300 rectangular as shown within the red line.
[image]

Today is another bad day with swing's setPreferredSize and setSize and all these size problems. Hope anyone could help, thanks!

```
    private JPanel buildInfoPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setVisible(false);

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        panel.setLayout(gbl);

        label_player = new JLabel("label_player");
        label_player.setBackground(Color.RED);
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbl.setConstraints(label_player, constraints);
        panel.add(label_player);

        label_deck = new JLabel("label_deck");
        label_deck.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        constraints.gridy++;
        gbl.setConstraints(label_deck, constraints);
        panel.add(label_deck);

        JTable table = new JTable(new ShipTableModel());
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(2);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
        constraints.gridy++;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        gbl.setConstraints(scrollPane, constraints);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        return panel;
    }

    class ShipTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private Ship[] ships = new Ship[0];
        private String[] columnNames = {"id", "name", "lv", "hp", "舰队", "舰种", "mId"};

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() { 
            return ships.length; 
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() { 
            return columnNames.length; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your current code? The best attempt you achieved.

Comment: Actually all you need is to call setPreferredSize  for the scrollpane containing JTable, and set weighty, and set fill = BOTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL` for the `JScrollPane`.